# Wireless button will not switch on

Tags: wifi

Basically, title... I'm new to this os as I just installed it. Google didn't return much.

Essentially, the wireless button will not go to the "on" position, however the ethernet button will.

Comment: Welcome to  elementaryos.se]. Before anyone can give you good answers they need more information about your system.  Please edit your question to include what computer you have and describe, as good as you can, what *does* happen and what you expect to happen. It also helps to know what you have tried already, so you don't get answers that tell you to try something when you already have.

Comment: It is a laptop, not sure of the specs at this current moment will update in due time though I could take an educated guess (~4gb, dual core, some integrated intel graphics card, and an SSD). Things I have tried: (keep in mind this is an entirely fresh install and I have basically no knowledge of it). Tried pressing the on button on the wireless setting - does not turn green. that's about it... just a little slider that won't go to the on position. I can upload pictures in the morning. Thanks

Comment: Under the question is a link to "edit" the question. Use that to update the infornation. Comments are considered temporary. What brand, and model of laptop is it? Your comment already helps since I was thinking it was a physical switch on the computer, but it seems it's the on-screen control that's part of the OS instead. I am assuming that the laptop does have WiFi built in or you wouldn't be trying to use it. Correct?

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm just going to uninstall elementary and go with ubuntu because it will run better on my system.

Comment: Same problem. I can disable wireless from drop-down network option. But can not do the opposite. Though I can do both when I am in settings.... Weird.